# Can't open web application made with Java EE on other local computers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to look the web application I made with Java EE. The server and database is up and running. It works on localhost:8080, but when I replace localhost with the local IP address all I get is a 404 error. Do I need to configure something?

Comment: is this on a linux or windows machine? What is the application server ? can you provide some relevant information...

Comment: The server is running on Windows 7 64 bit and trying to access it from an iPad and a MacBook Pro. Using Glassfish.

Comment: Have you in windows 7's firewall enable incoming and outgoing traffic for port 8080 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows 7 open the firewall to allow incoming and outgoing traffic on port 8080. Then from the remote machine make sure that you can ping the server's ip address and then try to browse to the address.

Comment: Thank you, I opened it in the firewall of my AntiVirus but not in Win 7. I thought the AntiVirus controlled the built in firewall as well